# my npm refused to install and i entered "npm config unsafe-perm true" and now i receive this error when trying to install

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

node:fs:723
handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
^

Error: EIO: i/o error, read
at Object.readSync (node:fs:723:3)
at tryReadSync (node:fs:433:20)
at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:471:19)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:18)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\exit-handler.js:4:22)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14) {
errno: -4070,
syscall: 'read',
code: 'EIO'
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I ran into this issue using VSCode and WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux). Fix was to restart WSL2 using wsl --shutdown or just restarting your machine. I believe the problem was that the virtual hard disk had run out of memory.